# Convert PDF to get vectorized text ("convert all text to outlines")

Tags: node.js, pdf, ghostscript, inkscape, pdftk

I'm using `nodejs` and I'm processing PDFs. One thing I'd like to do is to ***outline all the fonts of the PDF*** (so that they are not selectable with the mouse cursor afterwards).

I tried the `pdftk`'s `flatten` command (using a node wrapper), but I did not get what I wanted.

I may have a track in using `inkscape` (command line), but I'm not even sure about how to do it. I really am looking for the easiest way to do that using `nodejs`.

There might also be a track using ghostscript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798374/11348232. One notable thing to notice is that I don't use files on disk, but `Buffer` objects, so it'd be painful to save the PDF locally then use the `gs` command.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ghostscript is perfectly capable of accepting the PDF piped into stdin. It will then of course buffer the PDF to disk, but at least **you** don't have to save the PDF content. There is no JavaScript interface though, so you'd have to send the content from your buffer to stdin of a separate process. I rather suspect that saving the content to a local file might actually be easier. Using -dNoOutputFonts with the pdfwrite device will then produce a PDF file where all the 'text' is in fact simply linework. The resulting PDF will of course be a file on disk.

Comment: @KenS the output pdf has some defects: some borders around font characters have disappeared. Do you know an option to fix that?

Comment: @KenS I have a follow-up question there: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71558819/11348232

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally followed @KenS way:

```js
import util from 'util';
import childProcess from 'child_process';
import fs from 'fs';
import os from 'os';
import path from 'path';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const exec = util.promisify(childProcess.exec);

const unlinkCallback = (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

const deleteFile = (path: fs.PathLike) => {
  if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
    fs.unlink(path, unlinkCallback);
  }
};

const createTempPathPDF = () => path.join(os.tmpdir(), `${uuidv4()}.pdf`);

const convertFontsToOutlines = async (buffer: Buffer): Promise<Buffer> => {
  const inputPath = createTempPathPDF();
  const outputPath = createTempPathPDF();
  let bufferWithOutlines: Buffer;

  fs.createWriteStream(inputPath).write(buffer);

  try {
    // ! ghostscript package MUST be installed on system
    await exec(`gs -o ${outputPath} -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ${inputPath}`);

    bufferWithOutlines = fs.readFileSync(outputPath);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);

    bufferWithOutlines = buffer;
  }

  deleteFile(inputPath);
  deleteFile(outputPath);

  return bufferWithOutlines;
};
```