# PDF generated with ghostscript (no output fonts) has defects (missing outlines)

Tags: ghostscript

Following of question: [Convert PDF to get vectorized text ("convert all text to outlines")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71235810/11348232)

The PDF generated with the `gs -o outputPath.pdf -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite inputPath.pdf` has a defect. Around some font characters, some outlines have disappeared when I inspect it deeply with Inkscape (View / Display Mode / Outlines). See:

[image: screenshot of Inkscape view]

Link of the file for further inspection: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/nwsra9yl#link

How to solve this? Is there an option in the `ghostscript` command that I could add to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: It could simply be an error in the rendering engine (ie Inkscape), I'd have to see the file and look at the content to tell. If you aren't seeing the problem except when you zoom in a long way, then I'd have to suggest that's where the problem is. Fonts are treated specially by rendering engines to avoid this kind of thing (though more usually to avoid pixel dropout) regular linework isn't.

Comment: The same problem appears with Adobe Illustrator. The `inputPath.pdf` files has no such defects. I'll upload the file.

Comment: That file is not the same for me, can you upload the one you took the screenshot from?

Comment: I've tested and I confirm it is the good one. The only important thing is the visible text. Tell me if you really need the original file.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the text in the one you uploaded. Upload one that demonstrates the problem at least.

Comment: I updated the link. @mxmissile with which software did you open the file?

Comment: Where exactly in the file is your screenshot above? All the text looks fine on my end. Where exactly should I be looking? I'm using Chrome and Photoshop.

Comment: Using Adobe Acrobat X and I don't see a problem, but like mxmissile I don't really know where to look. The most likely 'VOTRE' is the text 'NOUS ATTENDONS VOTRE ACCORD' which for me is filled with black, not outlined as in your screenshot above. It seems to me that this could be because of your 'View Outlines' and in that case I really must point the finger at Inkscape. There **must** be an outline (closed path) there, or the ink would spill out of the path when it was filled. BTW 9.26 is a little old you should update.

Comment: Okok great, so for you there is not problem. I did not understand the version problem 9.26. Is it Inkscape version?